# Prove that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,a)$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I want to prove $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,a)$. I tried using the euclidean algorithm but that didn't help me much.

Comment: What definition of $gcd(a,b)$ do you operate with? Mine is obviously symmetric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\gcd(a,b)=x$ then $x \mid a$ and $x\mid b$ this implies $x \mid \gcd(b,a)$. By similar argument $\gcd(b,a)\mid\gcd(a,b).$ i.e., $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,a). $

Comment: ah thank you, i got very close to that argument but i couldn't quite put the last pieces together. I often struggle with these proofs.

Answer (score 2):

A divisor of $a$ and $b$ is a number $c$ such that $c\mid a$
and $c\mid b$. Note that a divisor of $a$ and $b$ is trivially a divisor
of $b$ and $a$.